# Output redirection from awk fails when executed from std::system call

Tags: c++, linux, windows, bash, awk

When running this command from a C++ program:

```
std::system("p4 print //perforce/path/to/file/configurations.json | grep -m 1 Configuration | awk '{sub(/,/, \"\"); sub(/\"/, \"\"); print $2}' > output.txt");
```

The command seems to work properly up until the call to awk, with the grep command outputting the expected string, but the awk command fails with the following error message:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file '>' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Awk seems to interpret the output redirection operator as the name of an input file.

For some reason this error happens when executed on Windows under Cygwin, but works fine when executed on Linux (compiled with MSVC 12 and gcc/4.8.1, respectively).

Comment: Did you consider using MinGW, and running a UNIX like shell from system?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin, so I have access to UNIX utilities.

Comment: Just so you know, you can turn your `grep | awk` into `awk '/Configuration/ {gsub(/[,\"]/, \"\", $2); print $2; exit}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '>' and '|' operators are functions of the shell.

The simplest route from here to there would be to execute the entire command string as a shell command.  i.e.  `std::system("cygwin/bin/bash -c \"command_string...\"")`

Just to clarify:  the default command shell will be used when the "system" call is made.   In a Linux system, that will be "bash."    In Windows, it will be "cmd"  (which is not the one you want)

Comment: I'm surprised Cygwin libc doesn't default to bash. (Or maybe it does and the OP didn't compile with Cygwin g++. I wonder...)

Comment: Cygwin can be installed anywhere, so the library doesn't necessarily know its location.

Comment: Thanks. Using `sh -c "..."` it seems to work properly when run from the Windows cmd command shell. 

I still don't understand why the command wouldn't work when run directly from cmd, since I can use awk and the output redirection operator ('>') from that shell without any problem.